# Unresponsive Appium Server & Device Offline problems

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

Below are some common problem encountered when performing tests using Appium with Selenium - especially when running the tests for hours.

**Some common Problems are:**

1. sometimes midway into the tests, appium cannot connect to the Device. Logs say Device is offline (even though the device is online & app is accessible, manually)
2. sometimes midway into the tests, the chromedriver in the case of webview becomes unresponsive.

**Questions:**

1. Keeping the Device Constant - Is there a way to restart the Appium Server and connect it to the existing instance of the Android Device. This way i can resume tests where it abruptly stopped.
2. Keeping the Appium Server Constant -  Is there a way to restart the APP on the Android Device and connect it to the existing instance of the Appium Server Session.
3. Is there some way to CHECK whether Appium Server and/or Android Device is offline / unresponsive ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether device is offline w.r.t appium by hitting `adb devices` in the command prompt.
If it displays the device only then its online to appium server

If Server becomes unresponsive it might be an intermittent stale session issue. Better to stop and restart server from command prompt by hitting `adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server`

Answer (score 0):

```
Few things can help you in minimising these issues drastically:
0. Put no lock and no screen saver on device.
1. Always start appium server before starting all tests, in case of testNG/junit framework, start in @BeforeClass or @BeforeTest method.
2. add this capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "120") to appium driver, this will stop appium to timeout early thus avoiding nosessionfound exception etc.
3. assuming you are using appium v16 and latest chromedriver v20: 
Problem: Chromedriver normally hangs while switching to and from webview but appium waits for chromedriver to respond until defined timeout and if it doesn't respond, appium gets timeout and then you may see hell lot of new issues like device not online, unknown error etc. 
Solution: You can keep monitoring chromedriver, when it stops responding, you can start it programmatically, this way your test will get going. 
Readymade solution: Download chromedriverhandler.jar from 
1. https://github.com/mi2pankaj/chromeDriverHandler, add to your project,
2. use this in beforeTest/beforeClass or at the start of your test: ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().start();
3. use this in afterTest/afterClass or at the end of your test: ChromedriverHandler.chromeDriverHandlerThread().stop();
Hope this helps!!
```